# SQL Query for Search Page

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

I am working on a small project for an online databases course and i was wondering if you could help me out with a problem I am having.

I have a web page that is searching a movie database and retrieving specific columns using a movie initial input field, a number input field, and a code field. These will all be converted to strings and used as user input for the query.

Below is what i tried before:

```
select A.CD, A.INIT, A.NBR, A.STN, A.ST, A.CRET_ID, A.CMNT, A.DT
from MOVIE_ONE A
where A.INIT = :init 
AND A.CD = :cd
AND A.NBR = :num
```

The way the page must search is in three different cases:

1. (initial and number)
2. (code)
3. (initial and number and code)

The cases have to be independent so if certain field are empty, but fulfill a certain case, the search goes through.  It also must be in one query. I am stuck on how to implement the cases.

**The parameters in the query are taken from the Java parameters in the method found in an SQLJ file.**

If you could possibly provide some aid on how i can go about this problem, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You need to tag your question with a specific SQL RDBMS, but generally you'd have each condition in your `where` clause return true if the parameter is empty; eg  something like `(A.INIT = :init or :init is null) and (A.CD = :cd or :cd is null)` etc.

Comment: I'm sure it was a typo, but you have a field called A.NBR in your select clause, and one called A._NBR in your where clause, and I suspect they refer to the same field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider wrapping the equality expressions in [`NVL`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_nvl.html) (synonymous to [`COALESCE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_coalesce.html)) so if parameter inputs are blank, corresponding column is checked against itself. Also, be sure to kick the [a-b-c table aliasing habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

```
SELECT m.CD, m.INIT, m.NBR, m.STN, m.ST, m.CRET_ID, m.CMNT, m.DT
FROM MOVIE_ONE m
WHERE m.INIT = NVL(:init, m.INIT)
AND m.CD = NVL(:cd, m.CD)
AND m.NBR = COALESCE(:num, m.NBR)
```

---

To demonstrate, consider below DB2 fiddles where each case can be checked by adjusting value CTE parameters all running on same exact data.

- [Case 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=2303c353ca0a4e4e3236de5a46ad4ac2)

  ```
  WITH 
   i(init) AS (VALUES('db2')),
   c(cd) AS (VALUES(NULL)),
   n(num) AS (VALUES(53)),
   cte AS
    ...
  ```
- [Case 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=1004da19a75a691400950385da3ce679)

  ```
  WITH 
   i(init) AS (VALUES(NULL)),
   c(cd) AS (VALUES(2018)),
   n(num) AS (VALUES(NULL)),
   cte AS
    ...
  ```
- [Case 3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=fedb162245678f630ab518936c2d5e05)

  ```
  WITH 
   i(init) AS (VALUES('db2')),
   c(cd) AS (VALUES(2018)),
   n(num) AS (VALUES(53)),
   cte AS
    ...
  ```

However, do be aware the fiddle runs a different SQL due to nature of data (i.e., double and dates). But query does reflect same concept with `NVL` matching expressions on both sides.

```
SELECT *
FROM cte, i, c, n
WHERE cte.mytype = NVL(i.init, cte.mytype)
AND YEAR(CAST(cte.mydate AS date)) = NVL(c.cd, YEAR(CAST(cte.mydate AS date)))
AND ROUND(cte.mynum, 0) = NVL(n.num, ROUND(cte.mynum, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have tried it based on your answer and it returns the desired output for case 1 and 2. Case 3 returns the output of case 2, which I’m assuming it should. I would imagine that it returns one row that matches all three parameters

Comment: It should. Carefully check that all three parameters are not empty and check closely the results. Post what you submit and results for case 3.

Comment: Actually, this answer DOES return the output for case 3. But for case 1 and 2 it does not return anything. If i switch the answer to: `where (m.INIT = NVL(:init, m.INIT) AND m.NBR = COALESCE(:num, m.NBR)) OR m.CD = NVL(:cd, m.CD)` ,  it will return cases 1 and 2 but not 3. @Parfait

Comment: Once again please post the parameters you pass and results your receive. I added a demo to show all cases return conditional results depending if parameters are `NULL` or not. Possibly what you post is more simplified than your actual. Be sure expressions match both sides. For instance if *cd* is a date and you want to match on year: `AND Year(m.CD) = NVL(:cd, Year(m.CD))`.

Comment: Also, I am not familiar with IBM's `SQLJ` library as it seems to handle `NULL` differently than usual application parameters. See [examples here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_c0057039.html). If you should use the popular Java, C#, PHP, Python, VB DB-APIs that connect to your DB2 and pass such parameters to prepared SQL statements, I assure this logic should work.